# ArgMin and NArgMin gives different result

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, maximum

Im doing the same problem with `ArgMin` and `NArgMin`, however NArgMin messes up the order of the solution.

Given function:

```
L[x_]=x a + (1+4/x) b;

NArgMin[{L, L'[1] == 0, L[1] == 100}, {a, b}]
{11.1111, 44.4444}
```

However:

```
ArgMin[{L, L'[1] == 0, L[1] == 100}, {a, b}] // N
{44.4444, 11.1111}
```

The correct result is `a = 44.4444`, `b = 11.1111` coming from ArgMin, where NArgMin swaps a and b.

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong? If I scale the problem to many more variables (a,b,c,...) I want to know what output corresponds to.

**Edit:** This is a bug I had in Mathematica version 11.3. After installing Version 12.0, both approaches gives the same answer.

Comment: The workaround in v11.3 is to use `NMinimize`, i.e., `{a, b} /. NMinimize[{L, L'[1] == 0, L[1] == 100}, {a, b}][[2]]`

Comment: Note that the first argument `L` is not valid.  Perhaps you meant `L[1]`?  (It's only a side issue here, because there is just one point satisfying the constraints.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me, which version of Mathematica are you using?

[image: Working]

Comment: Wow! I'm using 11.3.0.0 on Mac. Could you tell me your version?

Comment: Version Number: 12.0.0.0
Platform: Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

Comment: Thank you for response, I am downloading version 12 and will update the status.

Comment: I have installed Mathematica 12.0.0 and it is working perfectly as in the picture!